# Transfer a regression model from sample to raw data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series

Suppose that I have a single regression model predicting daily total store sales. Initially the model was trained on only 1% sample of the data and I applied min max normalization to the store sales. Now I gain access to the raw data, and would like to train the model on the raw data instead. How should I transfer the knowledge from the previous model to the current model given the magnitude of sales now changes? Maybe it does not matter too much cause I have applied min max normalization?

Comment: How are the raw data different? It is not clear to me why you have anything other than a larger data set.

Comment: the raw daily sales will be 100 times the sample daily sale. They are of different magnitude given that I am looking at aggregate daily sales.